# Auto refreshing after changing in redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How to automatically refresh the page after, for example, deleting something from the data? So i won't have manually refresh page to see changes. I'm using axios and js-server for data manipulation, if you need this information. I have this code:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { FetchUserList, RemoveUser } from "../Redux/Action";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const UserListing = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.loadUser();
  }, []);

  const handleDelete = (code) => {
    if (window.confirm("Do you want to remove?")) {
      props.removeUser(code);
      props.loadUser();
      toast.success("User removed successfully.");
    }
  };

  return props.user.loading ? (
    <div>
      <h2>Loading...</h2>
    </div>
  ) : props.user.errMessage ? (
    <div>
      <h2>{props.user.errMessage}</h2>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <>
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-header">
          <Link to={"/user/add"} className="btn btn-success">
            Add User [+]
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">
          <table className="table table-bordered table-dark">
            <thead className="">
              <tr>
                <td>Code</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Phone</td>
                <td>Role</td>
                <td>Action</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {props.user.userList &&
                props.user.userList.map((item) => (
                  <tr key={item.id}>
                    <td>{item.id}</td>
                    <td>{item.name}</td>
                    <td>{item.email}</td>
                    <td>{item.phone}</td>
                    <td>{item.role}</td>
                    <td>
                      <Link
                        to={"/user/edit/" + item.id}
                        className="btn btn-primary"
                      >
                        Edit
                      </Link>
                      <button
                        onClick={() => {
                          handleDelete(item.id);
                        }}
                        className="btn btn-danger"
                      >
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    user: state.user,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loadUser: () => dispatch(FetchUserList()),
    removeUser: (code) => dispatch(RemoveUser(code)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserListing);
```

Here's reducer:

```
import {
  ADD_USER,
  DELETE_USER,
  FAIL_REQUEST,
  GET_USER_LIST,
  MAKE_REQUEST,
} from "./ActionTypes";

const initialState = {
  loading: true,
  userList: [],
  userObj: {},
  errMessage: "",
};

export const Reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case MAKE_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };

    case FAIL_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        errMessage: action.payload,
      };

    case GET_USER_LIST:
      return {
        loading: false,
        errMessage: "",
        userList: action.payload,
        userObj: {},
      };
    case DELETE_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
      };
    case ADD_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And the actions file if you need:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  ADD_USER,
  DELETE_USER,
  FAIL_REQUEST,
  GET_USER_LIST,
  MAKE_REQUEST,
} from "./ActionTypes";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

export const makeRequest = () => {
  return {
    type: MAKE_REQUEST,
  };
};

export const failRequest = (err) => {
  return {
    type: FAIL_REQUEST,
    payload: err,
  };
};

export const getUserList = (data) => {
  return {
    type: GET_USER_LIST,
    payload: data,
  };
};

export const deleteUser = () => {
  return {
    type: DELETE_USER,
  };
};

export const addUser = () => {
  return {
    type: ADD_USER,
  };
};

export const FetchUserList = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(makeRequest());
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/user")
      .then((res) => {
        const userList = res.data;
        dispatch(getUserList(userList));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(failRequest(err.message));
      });
  };
};

export const RemoveUser = (code) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(makeRequest());
    axios
      .delete("http://localhost:8000/user/" + code)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(deleteUser());
        toast.success(
          "User removed successfully, please wait a couple of seconds."
        );
        setTimeout(() => {
          location.reload();
        }, 5000);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(failRequest(err.message));
      });
  };
};

export const FuncAddUser = (data) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(makeRequest());
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/user", data)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(addUser());
        toast.success("User added successfully.");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(failRequest(err.message));
      });
  };
};
```

Right now i solved problem by pretty primitive way, using setTimeout that restores the page after 5 seconds, but i'm sure this is not how it should work in prof programming

I saw some guys solves this with useEffect or useSelector, and was trying to do something similar, but still doesn't help

Comment: If you are updating `state.user` correctly then the component should "automagically" rerender on its own with the updated state. Can you [edit] to share the Redux code that is updating the `state.user` state?

Comment: Show your reducer

Comment: ok, i added reducer

Answer (score 0):

You are using redux so you can manage the state of users in store and you already managing for get only. I believe your FetchUserList action feching users from api and then updating the state of user. Now in case of delete, you just need to remove the user from store and boom redux will do rest for you because you are using connect. If props will change then your component will render with update users.

To remove, you can use filter function like this:

```
export function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "USER_DELETE_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        user: user.filter((u) => u.id !== id),
      };
      break;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure which redux middle ware you are using so I used a generic reducer. But if you can update your question with reducer code then I will be to help you with more relevant code

Answer (score 0):

The `RemoveUser` action dispatches a `deleteUser` action but doesn't specify *which* user should be removed. The `state.loading` value is updated and this will trigger a app/component rerender, but because the `state.user.userList` isn't updated the UI renders the same content as before the user was "removed.

Update the `deleteUser` action to consume a user id that should be removed.

```js
export const deleteUser = (userId) => {
  return {
    type: DELETE_USER,
    payload: userId,
  };
};
```

Update the `DELETE_USER` reducer case to update the `userList` state. Use `Array.prototype.filter` to filter the `userList` array, keeping all array elements that don't match by id.

```js
case DELETE_USER:
  const userId = action.payload;
  return {
    ...state,
    userList: state.userList.filter(user => user.id !== userId),
    loading: false,
  };
```

Update the `RemoveUser` action to pass the id of the user that will be deleted to the `deleteUser` action when it is dispatched. Remove the `setTimeout`/`window.location.reload` hack.

```js
export const RemoveUser = (userId) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(makeRequest());

  try {
    await axios.delete("http://localhost:8000/user/" + userId);
    dispatch(deleteUser(userId));
    toast.success(
      "User removed successfully, please wait a couple of seconds."
    );
  } catch(err) {
    dispatch(failRequest(err.message));
  };
};
```

After the `userList` state is updated and the app/component rerenders, it should also have the updated `state.user.userList` state value.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `location.reload();` and it waits 4 seconds for the "toast" if I helped you or you have questions please comment below:

```
const handleDelete = (code) => {
if (window.confirm("Do you want to remove?")) {
  props.removeUser(code);
  props.loadUser();
  toast.success("User removed successfully.");
  await wait(4000);
  window.location.reload();
}
```

};

Comment: It does reload the page after deleting, but the problem is now, that it stops my toast message from showing up. I'll find how to fix this, but if you know the answer that'd be much appreciated

Comment: This reloads the page, thus killing anything the app had in memory and was *going* to do. It's the same as if the user clicks the browser's reload button. Likely not behavior OP wants.

Comment: I updated my code maybe it will help now.

Comment: It doesnt kill anything what are you talking about?

Comment: It's less correct now, and likely won't compile since `await` can't be used.

Comment: The person that asked me didn’t write anything that it kills something?

Comment: I updated the answer to his problem with the „toast”

Comment: OFC they didn't ask, they told you with "...but the problem is now, that it stops my toast message from showing up."

Comment: Yes it stops becouse the „toast” can’t be shown becouse the website reloads too fast and not becouse this code kills something.

Comment: after adding the await it shows and waits for the toast